# React Native Component moves up with keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-softkeyboard, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-component

I create a custom bottom tab bar and fix it at end of screen using
`position: 'absolute',` and `bottom: 0,`.

---

---

I also have a textinput for search. When I try to type something in search, keyboard appears and with keyboard my bottom tab bar moves up.

---

---

Now, I want that the bottom tab bar not move with keyboard, it will stay on its place at bottom of screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, There are two ways to handle this kind of situation.

1. hide the bottom TabBar when keyboard is opening

- To hide TabBar when keyboard apprears there is one property that is provided by the react navigation itself is tabBarHideOnKeyboard.
- With this you can manage the visibility of TabBar when keyboard state changes.

eg.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
  }}
>
  {/** TabBar screens here */}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

2. manage the windowSoftInputMode in your AndroidManifest file.

- This will be the change in Native Code in the AndroidManifest.xml file
- This will require to reinstall the android app

eg.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...other_props
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" // make changes accordingly
>
```

Comment: I try this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and its working. Thanks 